# Trying to change the color of a shape used in textView background

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-drawable

I have a drawable oval defined in **xml** with a white background. I am setting this circle as the background resource of my `textView` inside my gridAdapter.

I want to change the color of the drawable circle by code, and I'm not having much luck. I have used `.setColor` , `.setColorFilter` and a variety of other hacks, but none have worked. The circle loads in the background of `textView` as **white**, it never seems to change.

Here I try to load the drawable and modify its color, and then add it as a background resource to the `textView`:

```
            int color = Color.parseColor(locationModel.col_line_color); // Color of the line

            GradientDrawable bgcircle = (GradientDrawable) gridContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle);
            bgcircle.mutate();
//          bgcircle.setColor(color);

            bgcircle.setColorFilter(color, Mode.SRC_ATOP);

            viewHolder.textView.setText((locationModel.col_line).toString());
            viewHolder.textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
```

The XML for the drawable shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="@android:color/white"/>

   <size 
       android:width="120dp"
       android:height="120dp"/>

</shape>
```

A lot of the tutorials call for `.mutate()` then to implement `.setColorFilter()`, but I haven't had much luck. I've tried changing the PorterDuff Mode to some alternatives, but the circles continue rendering white.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You trying to modify a xml resource at runtime which is not possible

Comment: So I would need to create the drawable in code then.

Comment: You can set drawables as background in your code. But you cannot modify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of tyring to modify the current xml drawable, Create the drawable in your code. you can also use [ShapeDrawable](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html&ei=_IFrUYXyNs2uiQf2jIHgDQ&usg=AFQjCNEkCc7devFnVf9xKbfi4AfBpfMSvw&sig2=ZXI23WrfRM4pZ-UlCOy-iA&bvm=bv.45175338,d.aGc) if you dont need gradient.

```
ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
drawable.getPaint().setColor(newColor);
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing this, and passing the drawable as the background resource. However I'm getting a "deprecated" warning for `setBackgroundDrawable`, is it better to use `setBackground`?

Comment: it is always better to use non depcrecated methods